# com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Requiring unknown module "./locale/ID".,

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, react-native

I just released an apk that was made using the native framework.

The application runs nominally but there are some errors in the features that make it forced to close.

I tried to debug the error of using an android studio logcat and I found this exception:

```
2019-03-12 16:08:36.163 28143-28185/? E/ReactNativeJS: Requiring unknown module "./locale/ID".
2019-03-12 16:08:36.172 28143-28185/? E/ReactNativeJS: Requiring unknown module "./locale/id".
2019-03-12 16:08:36.183 28143-28186/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
Process: com.awesomeproject, PID: 28143
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Requiring unknown module "./locale/ID"., stack:
d@2:595
n@2:339
t@2:262
pt@914:16946
kt@914:17972
wt@914:17035
value@928:2775
f@41:42083
beginWork@41:45676
o@41:64674
a@41:65053
T@41:68561
y@41:67997
v@41:67834
batchedUpdates@41:72172
Ie@41:14848
ze@41:15343
receiveTouches@41:16180
value@18:3582
<unknown>@18:1067
value@18:3009
value@18:1039

    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:54)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:38)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:160)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

solved, I have imported `import Moment from 'moment';` but I tried to change the Indonesian time zone, like this `Moment.locale ('ID');` and I tried removing the code and releasing it again.